# defining a method using inherited methods

Tags: java, generics, constructor, super, inheritance

I'm trying to define void `add(T thing)` method by using the inherited push method of a stack but Eclipse says the return type is incompatible with `Vector<T>.add(T)` and wants me to change the return type of `add(T)` to boolean which doesn't make sense. 
Below is my code

```
public class ListStack<T> extends Stack<T> implements SomeList<T>{
   Stack<T> stack1=new Stack<T>();
public ListStack(){//constructor
    super();
    stack1=new Stack<T>();
 }
//add method
 public void add(T something){
    this.push(something);}
}
```

Here's my `SomeList` interface

```
public interface SomeList<T>{
public void add(T something);
public void take(T idx);
  .
  . 
  .
}
```

Comment: This is why we prefer composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since you're holding an instance of `Stack<T>` as member you don't need to inherit from the very same class.

Remove the inheritance and use your member instead:

```
public void add(T something){
    stack1.push(something);
}
```

If you no longer subclass `Stack<T>` your compiler shouldn't complain about the different return types of `add(T)` anymore.

---

I think you should have a look into the [adapter pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter).

Here's how I would do it:

**Interface**

```
interface MyList<T> {
    public void addFront(T thing);

    public void remove(int pos);

    public void removeEnd();

    public T get(int pos);

    public int length();

    public boolean isEmpty();

}
```

**Implementation**

```
class MyListImpl<T> implements MyList {
    Stack<T> mStack;

    public MyListImpl() {
        mStack = new Stack<T>();
    }

    public void addFront(T thing) {
        mStack.push(thing);
    }

    public void remove(int pos) {
        //mStack...
    }

    public void removeEnd() {
        //mStack...
    }

    public T get(int pos) {
        // return mStack...
    }

    public int length() {
        // return mStack... 
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // return mStack...
    }
```

}

Comment: But then then I get an error on pop() and push. Since they are undefined.

Comment: Yeah that is the result. But I can't really see why you would need to provide push/pop and add/take methods, since they would do the same anyway. Can you give more information about what you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm tying to implement a ListStack data structure that only uses stack operations of pop(), push, isEmpty() and peek(). It implements an Interface List<T> which has the following methods `addFront(T thing)` which adds things to the front of the list `remove(int pos)` which removes items from some position pos `removeEnd()` which removes things from the end of the structure `get(int pos)` which gets the things at a specfic position in the structure,  `int length()` which returns the size of  the structure and lastly `isEmpty()` which returns true if the structure is empty and false if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Stack Class` must be having the method `add()` with a return type of `boolean`

Answer (score 0):

`Stack` class extends `Vector` class, which contains `boolean add(E e)`. I think Eclipse confuses between the `add` method in `Vector`, and the `add` method in your `SomeList` interface.